# How to make NPM package manager refer to my version of a library?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, package-managers

I want to make a bug fix in an NPM library.

How to make my software using `package.json` to refer to my version of the library (probably a directory on my disk with the library) rather than to the "standard" version of the library from `npmjs.org`, so that I would be able to debug my version of the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to run `npm install` like you normally would. The only difference is that instead of doing `npm install <package-name>`, you're going to do `npm install /path/to/local/package`

[Here's an article explaining in more detail](https://medium.com/@the1mills/how-to-test-your-npm-module-without-publishing-it-every-5-minutes-1c4cb4b369be)